# Cannot start PostgreSQL Docker container – "'/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/': Operation not permitted"

Tags: postgresql, docker, permission-denied

Trying to start a PostgreSQL container according to the instructions at https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres (*How to use this image* → *start a postgres instance*),

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres:14
```

gives the following error:

> ls: cannot access '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/': Operation not permitted

The only change was removing the `--name` and `-d` parameter while using the version tag `14` of PostgreSQL. But even with the exact same command from Docker Hub the same error shows up.

Why is that and how can it be fixed? Is it a bug in the PostgreSQL image or a system configuration issue?

---

Additional information:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:    17.12.0-ce
 API version:    1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built:    Wed Dec 27 20:10:45 2017
 OS/Arch:    linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:    17.12.0-ce
  API version:    1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:    go1.9.2
  Git commit:    c97c6d6
  Built:    Wed Dec 27 20:09:19 2017
  OS/Arch:    linux/amd64
  Experimental:    false

$ uname -r
5.13.0-16-generic

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=impish
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.10"

$ docker images postgres:latest
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
postgres            latest              14e58c3f6369        6 days ago          374MB
$ docker images postgres:14
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
postgres            14                  14e58c3f6369        6 days ago          374MB
```

It looks like it works with `postgres:14-alpine`.

Comment: can you try upgrading Docker?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I bumped into the same issue.

PostgreSQL Docker tags `13` and `14` seem to be using Debian's `bullseye` which seems to change things in regards to the file system.

At the moment there are two solutions:

1. Downgrade to PostgreSQL `13-buster`, i.e. Docker tag `postgres:13.4-buster`, as it seems `14` does not have a `-buster` equivalent.
2. Upgrade current Docker you are running. From Docker version onwards `20.10.6`, it seems to fix the issue.

As a reference to the issue on GitHub related to this issue, you can find it at *[root user has no permissions within container #884](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/884)* .

For posterity, the solution from GitHub:

> you'll need to update Docker, runc, and likely libseccomp on your
> host.

Answer (score 6):

If you cannot or don't want to – for whatever reason – upgrade Docker, a quick workaround is to use a different tag, such as `postgres:14-alpine`.

Comment: Thanks, works for me on CentOS 7 with Docker 19.03.5.

Answer (score 1):

Problem occurs with version **postgres:12.9** upgrade to version **postgres:13-alpine** fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: run docker with privileged mode !

Comment: And how do you do that? Can you provide the command (and some references?)

Comment: With docker cli: `docker run -d --privileged postgres:15 bash`